# How to get all values of an enum in PHP?

Tags: php, php-8.1

PHP 8.1 is almost getting released, including support for Enumerations. I was testing some of the enum functionality and couldn't find much documentation about it. Hence my question: how do I get all values of an enum?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

For basic enums:

```
$suits = array_column(Suit::cases(), 'name');
```

For backed enums where you want the values:

```
$suits = array_column(Suit::cases(), 'value');
```

You could then do something like this:

```
trait EnumToArray
{

  public static function names(): array
  {
    return array_column(self::cases(), 'name');
  }

  public static function values(): array
  {
    return array_column(self::cases(), 'value');
  }

  public static function array(): array
  {
    return array_combine(self::values(), self::names());
  }

}

enum Suit: string
{

  use EnumToArray;

  case Hearts = 'H';
  case Diamonds = 'D';
  case Clubs = 'C';
  case Spades = 'S';

}
```

`Suit::array()` will return:

```
Array
(
    [H] => Hearts
    [D] => Diamonds
    [C] => Clubs
    [S] => Spades
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I flipped `array_combine(self::names(), self::values())`. Having the names as array keys feels more natural to me.

Comment: Thx, I added a `containsValue()` function `return \in_array($value, self::values(), true);`

Comment: @v.nivuahc You can just use `tryFrom` for that: https://www.php.net/manual/en/backedenum.tryfrom.php

Answer (score 44):

After some research I found [the answer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/unitenum.cases.php). You can use the static method: `cases()`.

```php
enum Status
{
    case PAID;
    case Cancelled;
}

Status::cases();
```

The cases method will return an array with an enum (`UnitEnum` interface) for each value.

Comment: you can also read about enum methods for PHP 8.1 at the [link](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/enums#enum-use-cases)

Answer (score 6):

**Need the values and not Enum instances?**

I've [written a Composer package](https://github.com/othyn/php-enum-enhancements) for this, `othyn/php-enum-enhancements`,  as the `UnitEnum::cases()` method wasn't what I was looking for, as that returns an array of `MySuperCoolEnum` instances instead of the underlying values as their raw type, which is what I wanted.

Its a trait that can be easily added to any enum that does the following:

- Adds a new static `UnitEnum::valueArray(): array` method that returns all values within an Enum as an equally typed array of Enum values
- Adds a new static `UnitEnum::valueList(string $separator = ', '): string` method that returns all values within an Enum as a comma separated list string

In which produces the following for *normal* Enum's:

```
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

use Othyn\PhpEnumEnhancements\Traits\EnumEnhancements;

enum TestEnum
{
    use EnumEnhancements;

    case Alpha;
    case Bravo;
    case Charlie;
    case Delta;
    case Echo;
}

var_dump(TestEnum::valueArray());

// Results in the following being printed:
// array(5) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(5) "Alpha"
//   [1]=>
//   string(5) "Bravo"
//   [2]=>
//   string(7) "Charlie"
//   [3]=>
//   string(5) "Delta"
//   [4]=>
//   string(4) "Echo"
// }

var_dump(TestEnum::valueList());

// Results in the following being printed:
// string(34) "Alpha, Bravo, Charlie, Delta, Echo"

var_dump(TestEnum::valueList(separator: ':'));

// Results in the following being printed:
// string(30) "Alpha:Bravo:Charlie:Delta:Echo"
```

... and the following for Backed Enum's, the following being a `string` example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

use Othyn\PhpEnumEnhancements\Traits\EnumEnhancements;

enum TestStringBackedEnum: string
{
    use EnumEnhancements;

    case Alpha   = 'alpha';
    case Bravo   = 'bravo';
    case Charlie = 'charlie';
    case Delta   = 'delta';
    case Echo    = 'echo';
}

var_dump(TestStringBackedEnum::valueArray());

// Results in the following being printed:
// array(5) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(5) "alpha"
//   [1]=>
//   string(5) "bravo"
//   [2]=>
//   string(7) "charlie"
//   [3]=>
//   string(5) "delta"
//   [4]=>
//   string(4) "echo"
// }

var_dump(TestStringBackedEnum::valueList());

// Results in the following being printed:
// string(34) "alpha, bravo, charlie, delta, echo"

var_dump(TestStringBackedEnum::valueList(separator: ':'));

// Results in the following being printed:
// string(30) "alpha:bravo:charlie:delta:echo"
```

... and yes it works on `int`'s too!

There are more examples in the [Usage part of the package's README](https://github.com/othyn/php-enum-enhancements#usage).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to `UnitEnum::cases()` you can use [`ReflectionEnum`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionenum.php) with this

```
$reflection = new ReflectionEnum(Status::class);

$reflection->getCases();
```

note that in both cases you will not be able to get the enum methods. but as long as the `ReflectionEnum` is extending the `ReflectionClass` so you can use the rest of ReflectionClass methods such as `getMethods`

Comment: This is a lot better than the accepted answer. I prefer `Reflection` for all things classes, interfaces, enums..

Comment: How is this better than just `Status::cases()`?

Answer (score 4):

I have used the following in my project;

```php
public static function toAssociativeArray(): array
{
    foreach(self::cases() as $case) {
        $array[$case->value] = $case->name;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Which results in an associative array like this;

using strings as values

```php
enum DiaryRole: string
{
    case DANGER  = 'red';
    case WARNING = 'yellow';
    case SAFE    = 'green';
}

$array = [
    'red'    => 'DANGER',
    'yellow' => 'WARNING',
    'green'  => 'SAFE'
];
```

or when using integers as values

```php
enum DiaryRole: int
{
    case DANGER  = 1;
    case WARNING = 2;
    case SAFE    = 3;
}

$array = [
    1 => 'DANGER',
    2 => 'WARNING',
    3 => 'SAFE'
];
```

You can now use the array to get any information you need, and you can get only the columns or values using `array_keys()` or `array_values()`

I have used this code to easily foreach through them in a form select

Answer (score 2):

I think the best options is using a trait for that.

For example:
EnumsToArray.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait EnumsToArray {
    public static function toArray(): array {
        return array_map(
            fn(self $enum) => $enum->value, 
            self::cases()
        );
    }
}
```

And later, in you enum you should have:

```
use App\Traits\EnumsToArray;

Enum Currency: string {
    use EnumsToArray;
    
    case DOLLAR = "usd";
    case EURO = "eur";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrapped a slitly changed approach from @Michael up in a small package, cause I needed it in multiple projects:

https://github.com/laracraft-tech/laravel-useful-traits#usefulenums

**Install** via composer:

```
composer require laracraft-tech/laravel-useful-traits
```

This is how it is working:

```php
use LaracraftTech\LaravelUsefulTraits\UsefulEnums;

enum PaymentType: int
{
    use UsefulEnums;

    case Pending = 1;
    case Failed = 2;
    case Success = 3;
}

PaymentType::names();   // return ['Pending', 'Failed', 'Success']
PaymentType::values();  // return [1, 2, 3]
PaymentType::array();   // return ['Pending' => 1, 'Failed' => 2, 'Success' => 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get just the values of the enum is by following this approach:

```php
<?php namespace JCKCon\Enums;

enum UsersPermissions: string
{
    case CREATE = "create";
    case UPDATE = "update";
    case DELETE = "delete";
    case VIEW = "view";
    case PUBLISH = "publish";

    public static function toArray()
    {
        $values = [];

        foreach (self::cases() as $props) {
            array_push($values, $props->value);
        }

        return $values;
    }
}


dd(UsersPermissions::toArray());

/**
array:5 [
  0 => "create"
  1 => "update"
  2 => "delete"
  3 => "view"
  4 => "publish"
]
**/
```

Comment: `value` is not a defined property in this case. You should use `$props->name`. Also, I would rewrite the the `toArray` method to this: `return array_map(fn($case) => $case->name, self::cases());`.

Comment: Ignore this part `value is not a defined property in this case. You should use $props->name`.  I didn't pay attention to it to see it's a backed enum. Whoops

Comment: Okay great!. You can vote the answer to help others then.